# How to set opacity of ImageView layer border

Tags: ios, swift, opacity

How to set profile Border opacity ?

How to set transparent for having opacity of border color with .white of 50% opacity.

```
profileView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
profileView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `withAlphaComponent`:

```
profileView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
```

or:

```
profileView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor.copy(alpha: 0.5)
```

Obviously you can choose whatever alpha value you want in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

Or in this case you can use:

```
profileView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
```

Comment: Not alpha I'am trying, I need "opacity".  both are different alpha & opacity.

Comment: @kiran When you say you want 50% opacity do you mean you want it to be semi-transparent? That is what setting `alpha` does.

Comment: @kiran - there is no such thing as "**border opacity**." You can set the **alpha** of the view... you can set the **opacity** of a ***layer***... you can set the **alpha** of a layer's background color (or fill color if it's a shape layer path)... and you can set the **alpha** of a layer's **borderColor** (or stroke color if it's a shape layer path).

Comment: @kiran Where does this stand? Did this answer actually do what you needed? If not, can you clarify what you want differently?

Answer (score -1):

for alternative you can add UIView behind and set it as border of you ImageView, it's easier to set the oppacity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).